# Assign result from dynamic SQL in a parameter to another parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I'm having to build my query dynamically, firstly, it gets the maxlogid from the log, and appends this to the temporary table name. Then it does a COALESCE to return the distinct values into a string.

However, the output of the string, I want to have in a parameter, so I can use it again later on within a dynamic sql query.

Here is my code;

```
DECLARE @maxLogId VARCHAR(10)
SELECT @maxLogId = (SELECT Max(id) FROM dbo.tLog)   

DECLARE @PolicyTempTable VARCHAR(100)
SET @PolicyTempTable = '##tPols' + @maxLogId

DECLARE @emailParm NVARCHAR(1000) 
SET @emailParm = N'DECLARE @email VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT COALESCE(@email+'','' ,'''') + '''''''''''' + EMAIL + '''''''''''' 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT EMAIL FROM ' + @PolicyTempTable + ') d'

EXEC sp_executesql @emailParm
```

The results are returned as follows;

"abc@a.co.uk",""abc@b.co.uk"

I want to be able to write the sp_executesql into a seperate parameter, so I can use for a dynamic query like below;

```
DECLARE @StrSQLEmail VARCHAR(8000)
SET @StrSQLEmail = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(ATOM,''Select * from ATOMS.EMAILS WHERE EMAIL IN (' + '' EXEC sp_executesql @emailParm + '' + ')'')'
```

However, I can't use the sp_executesql within my dynamic query.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: @jarlh Almost certainly SQL Server.

Comment: Yes, SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use parameters with sp_executesql

```
DECLARE @emailParm NVARCHAR(1000) 
DECLARE @emailOut NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @emailParm = N'SELECT COALESCE(@email+'','' ,'''') + '''''''''''' + EMAIL + '''''''''''' 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT EMAIL FROM ' + @PolicyTempTable + ') d'

EXEC sp_executesql @emailParm, N'@email VARCHAR(1000) OUTPUT', @email = @emailOut OUTPUT
```

Then you can build your second dynamic sql

```
DECLARE @StrSQLEmail VARCHAR(8000)
SET @StrSQLEmail = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(ATOM,''Select * from ATOMS.EMAILS WHERE EMAIL IN (' + @emailOut + ')'')'
```